# Создание адресной книги

Tags: python-3.x

Я начинающий программист, читая книгу 'Укус питона', в конце нам дали задание('Создать адресную книгу, в которую можно будет добавить, удалять людей и изменять её. Кроме того, эта информация также должна сохраняться на диске для последующего доступа.)
**Моя проблема** состоит, в том что у меня никак не получается сделать папку с сохранениями, с которыми в дальнейшем можно будет работать.  Что у меня не так? По возможности скинуть отредактированный код. СПАСИБО!

```
import pickle 
addressbook = 'address.data'


#  ab - сокращение от 'a'ddress'b'ook
class AddressBook:  
    ab = {}  
    address_count = 0  # количество адрессов

    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        AddressBook.ab[key] = value

    @staticmethod
    def look():
        '''Посмотрим кто у нас уже добавлен'''
        f = open(addressbook, 'rb')
        address = pickle.load(f)
        if AddressBook.address_count == 1:
            print('Всего у нас {0:d} адрес'.format(AddressBook.address_count))
        elif AddressBook.address_count < 5 and AddressBook.address_count != 0:
            print('Всего у нас {0:d} адреса'.format(AddressBook.address_count))
        else:
            print('Всего у нас {0:d} адресов'.format(AddressBook.address_count))
        for i in AddressBook.ab:
            print(i, ':', AddressBook.ab[i])
        print(address)

    @staticmethod
    def look_by_key():
        try:
            key = input('Введите имя пользователя --> ')
        except KeyError:
            print('К сожалению, у вас не добавлен этот пользователь')
        else:
            print('Почта: {0}'.format(AddressBook.ab[key]))

    @staticmethod
    def add():
        name = input('Введите имя пользоваетля --> ')
        address = input('Введите почту пользователя --> ')
        AddressBook(name, address)
        # При создании этой личности, адресс добавляется
        # к переменной 'address_count'
        AddressBook.address_count += 1
        print('Адрес Успешно добавлен')
        f = open(addressbook, 'wb')
        pickle.dump(AddressBook.ab, f)
        pickle.dump(AddressBook.address_count, f)
        f.close()

    @staticmethod
    def add_more():
        name = input('Введите имя пользоваетля --> ')
        AddressBook.ab[name] = input('Введите почту пользователя --> ')
        f = open(addressbook, 'wb')
        pickle.dump(AddressBook.ab, f)
        f.close()

    @staticmethod
    def delete():
        '''Rest in peace'''
        name = input('Введите имя --> ')
        del AddressBook.ab[name]
        print('Адрес {0} удален!'.format(name))
        AddressBook.address_count -= 1

    @staticmethod
    def exit_code():
        exit()

    @staticmethod
    def menu():
        f = open(addressbook, 'rb')
        address = pickle.load(f)
        print(address)
        x = -1
        while x != 6:
            print('1. Вывод - 1\n'
                  '2. Добавить - 2 \n'
                  '3. Удалить - 3 \n'
                  '4. Задать ключ - 4 \n'
                  '5. Посмотреть по ключу - 5 \n'
                  '6. Выход - 6 \n')
            x = int(input('Выберите подходящую для вас цифру --> '))
            if x == 1:
                AddressBook.look()
            elif x == 2:
                AddressBook.add()
            elif x == 3:
                AddressBook.delete()
            elif x == 4:
                AddressBook.add_more()
            elif x == 5:
                AddressBook.look_by_key()
            elif x == 6:
                AddressBook.exit_code()


AddressBook.menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

Удобнее в этом случае как мне кажется будет создать базу данных и записывать все в нее. Это можно сделать при помощи sqlite3, чтобы просмотреть все записи в бд можно выводить каждую строку циклом или с помощью "DB browser for sqlite" https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/
Ну а если вам нужна папка
import os
os.mkdir("путь и название папки")